# Formatted Vs Unformatted Hard Drive Read/Wrtie Issue

Tags: c++, performance

I am trying to read a large amount of data (~TB) from two solid state drives (SSDs) (ideally unformatted) and combine the data by a certain algorithm and write it back to another SSD. Initially I implemented a program that reads from two FORMATTED hard drives (OS sees it) and writes to another formatted hard drive. I was able to get about 450 MB/Sec speed (for the whole program). I was using fread() to read data from SSDs.

Then I implemented it with reading from two UNFORMATTED SSDs and writing to a formatted SSD and I am only getting about 200 MB/sec. I am still using fread() and I am puzzled why the speed is slower. To read unformatted hard drives I have to run in the Admin mode and use HANDLE and then cast it to a file pointer by the time I read bytes. So, once the correct hard drives are found the code is the same and I am using freads(). The code is listed below for a test program I used to measure the speed of the formatted vs unformatted reads. In this program I am getting about 200 MB/sec for UNFORMATTED hard drive reads and 500 MB/sec for FORMATTED hard drive reads.

Formatted read program.

```
while (tempCounter < frames_to_process)   //
{

    if (fread(frame_header_A, 1, 212052, pFile_A) != 212052) {

        printf("Couldn't read 212052 Bytes\n");
        if (feof(pFile_A))
        {
            printf("End of File reached while reading the frame\n");
            cout << "Num iterations " << tempCounter << endl;

        }
        if (ferror(pFile_A))
        {
            printf("Error reading file while reading for the frame\n");
        }

        time2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        time_span = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(time2 - time1);

        cout << "time to create imagery files " << setprecision(10) << time_span.count() << " seconds" << endl << endl;

        exit(0);
        return 0;

    }






    tempCounter++;


    //let's Check whether the variable end with 0xBCB55757


    container_count_A = 1;
    container_count_B = 2;

    if ((frame_header_A[212048] == (char)0xBC) && (frame_header_A[212049] == (char)0xB5) && (frame_header_A[212050] == (char)0x57) && (frame_header_A[212051] == (char)0x57))
    {
        unsigned int byte_1 = frame_header_A[27];
        unsigned int byte_2 = frame_header_A[26];
        unsigned int byte_3 = frame_header_A[25];
        unsigned int byte_4 = frame_header_A[24];

    }


}
```

Unformatted reads program. Essentially, it iterates though all connected hard drives and find the specific hard drive A and B using a certain pattern. After that the HANDLE is casted to a regular file pointer and then reuses the code above (formatted case)

```
FILE *pFile_A = NULL;
FILE *pFile_B = NULL;
FILE* f = NULL;


ofstream writeBinary_Combine;

writeBinary_Combine.open(argv[2], ofstream::out | ofstream::binary);
//


LPCTSTR dsksrc = L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive";
wchar_t dsk[512] = L"";


int fd;
bool channel_A_found = false;
bool channel_B_found = false;
char frame_header_A[212052];  //seems I can't have another 
char frame_header_B[212052];

unsigned int container_count_A = 1;
unsigned int container_count_B = 2;


char* frame_header_test = new char[212052];  // for some reason I am running out of static memory; so I am using heap to alleviate it ???


HANDLE hDisk;

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{


    swprintf(dsk, 511, L"%s%d", dsksrc, i);

    hDisk = CreateFile(dsk, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, NULL, NULL);
    if (hDisk == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {

        printf("%s%d%s", "couldn't open the drive ", i, "\n");
        CloseHandle(hDisk);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s%d%s", "successfully open the drive ", i, "\n");
        fd = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)hDisk, _O_RDONLY);

        char buff_test[500000];
        if (fd != -1)
        {
            f = _fdopen(fd, "rb");
            int ret_code = 0;

            char drive_header[512];
            fread(drive_header, 1, 512, f);

            if ((drive_header[510] == (char)0x55) && (drive_header[511] == (char)0xAA))  //  test for a formatted drive; is there other identifiers?
            {
                //bootable drive; not an unformatted drive no need to keep on searching
                //_close(fd);
            }

            else
            {
                fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
                ret_code = find_BCB55757(f, i);

                if (ret_code != -1)
                {
                    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
                    fread(buff_test, 1, ret_code, f);
                    fread(frame_header_test, 1, 212052, f);

                    unsigned int readout_B = 1;
                    unsigned int cmdout_B = 2;

                    unsigned int byte_1 = frame_header_test[115];
                    unsigned int byte_2 = frame_header_test[114];
                    unsigned int byte_3 = frame_header_test[113];
                    unsigned int byte_4 = frame_header_test[112];

                    readout_B = ((byte_4 << 24) & 0xff000000) | ((byte_3 << 16) & 0x00ff0000) | ((byte_2 << 8) & 0x0000ff00) | (byte_1 & 0x000000ff);

                    byte_1 = frame_header_test[123];
                    byte_2 = frame_header_test[122];
                    byte_3 = frame_header_test[121];
                    byte_4 = frame_header_test[120];

                    cmdout_B = ((byte_4 << 24) & 0xff000000) | ((byte_3 << 16) & 0x00ff0000) | ((byte_2 << 8) & 0x0000ff00) | (byte_1 & 0x000000ff);

                    //cout << readout_B << "  " << cmdout_B << endl;

                    size_t result_1 = 0;

                    if (readout_B == (cmdout_B - 1))
                    {
                        channel_B_found = true;
                        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);              //this is the only way to do it
                        result_1 = fread(buff_test, 1, ret_code, f);

                        if (result_1 != (size_t)ret_code)
                        {
                            cout << "reading error 1 " << endl;
                            cout << "read bytes " << result_1 << endl;
                        }


                        result_1 = fread(frame_header_B, 1, 212052, f);
                        if (result_1 != (size_t)212052)
                        {
                            cout << "reading error 2" << endl;
                            cout << "read bytes " << result_1 << endl;
                        }

                        pFile_B = f;

                        byte_1 = frame_header_B[27];
                        byte_2 = frame_header_B[26];
                        byte_3 = frame_header_B[25];
                        byte_4 = frame_header_B[24];



                        cout << "found B" << endl;

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        channel_A_found = true;
                        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);              //this is the only way to do it
                        result_1 = fread(buff_test, 1, ret_code, f);

                        if (result_1 != (size_t)ret_code)
                        {
                            cout << "reading error 5" << endl;
                            cout << "read bytes " << result_1 << endl;
                        }

                        result_1 = fread(frame_header_A, 1, 212052, f);

                        if (result_1 != (size_t)212052)
                        {
                            cout << "reading error 6" << endl;
                            cout << "read bytes " << result_1 << endl;
                        }

                        pFile_A = f;

                        byte_1 = frame_header_A[27];
                        byte_2 = frame_header_A[26];
                        byte_3 = frame_header_A[25];
                        byte_4 = frame_header_A[24];




                        cout << "found A" << endl;

                    }
                }
                //fclose(f);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            _close(fd);
        }

    }

    if (channel_A_found && channel_B_found)
    {
        cout << "both drives found" << endl;
        break;
    }
}// then reuse the code from the formatted case
```

Here are my questions.

1) why is the speed in the unformatted case lot slower although I am using the same fread(). Does it have to do with setting up reading physical drives the HANDLE

2) Is there a way to improve the speed of the unformatted hard drives? should I be using read() instead of fread() in the unformatted case?

I appreciate any help or ideas!

Comment: Can't find a documentation reference, but it's likely that you need to use setbuf or setvbuf on your new FILE* after doing _open_osfhandle to set a sensible buffer size, probably not smaller than 256k, you can experiment with larger sizes to see where the sweet spot for read performance is.

Comment: A wild guess: unformatted drive may have some difficulty in handling discarded data, so if you don't overwrite a whole block, it will end up a read and a write. And I think you should at least try system function first. And as it seems that you are using WindowsNT try Read/WriteFile or even NtRead/WriteFile